# Laravel: 5.1: Eloquent filter when authenticating a user with JWT

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

We have a users table that contains data (e.g. username, password, etc etc) and is classified by country using a column country_id. The app will use laravel JWT authentication however I need to filter is by country because users might have the same username. Is this possible by authenticating with accompanying filter?

e.g.

```
$credentials = array(
        'username' => $request->json('username'),
        'password' => $request->json('password')
        'country' => static::COUNTRY_ID
    );

$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)
```

Comment: Good question. Does this help? https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/952 I'd be interested to see more code.

Comment: @admcfajn you are right! The link helped thank you very much!

Comment: Very welcome! Please consider the country argument in persistent storage `&&||` separate requests.

Comment: @admcfajn thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for me it worked like this:

```
$credentials = array_merge($request->only(['email', 'password']), ['active' => 1, 'confirmed' => 1]);

    try {
        $token = $JWTAuth->attempt($credentials);
        $user = auth()->user();
        if (!$token) {
            throw new AccessDeniedHttpException();
        }
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        throw new HttpException(Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
```